# Flutter, Unable to convert string to date

Tags: flutter

I'd like to convert a string to Date but I get this error when display date in Text :

> Trying to read / from 2020-04-18 19:43:43.755927 at position 5

and this is the function

```
String get dateNote {
   var d = DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", "en_US").parse(createdAt);
   return d.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String date = '2020-04-18 19:43:43.755927';

  String getFormattedDate(String date) {
  var d = DateTime.parse(date);
  return   [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ][d.month - 1] +
      " " +   d.day.toString() +
      "," +
      d.year.toString();
}


  print(getFormattedDate(date));
```

**Output :** Apr 18,2020

Comment: I found a short solution , you can check it

Answer (score 0):

I found a short solution:

```
String get dateNote {
  var date = DateTime.parse(createdAt);
  var strDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date).toString();
  return strDate;
}
```